# Unable to unmarshal my xml

Tags: jaxb, unmarshalling

I am sending a request to webservice and am receiving correct response from web service in xml format with the correct value populated in the response element tage. Now I tried to unmarshal but the response object is being populated with null instead of the value I see in XML response.

Any obvious thing to check?
This is my code:

```
InputSource outputSource = getWebServiceHelper().send(source,messageIdentifier);

JAXBElement<Envelope> responseEnv = (JAXBElement<Envelope>) getWebServiceHelper().unmarshal(new SAXSource(outputSource));
JAXBElement<ResponseObjectType> result = (JAXBElement<ResponseObjectType>)responseEnv.getValue().getBody().getAny().get(0);
```

The moment second line executes, the response attribute is becoming null. Despite being correct between xml tags!

Thanks a ton.
Chaitanya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution myself through intense trial and error. Here is how I got it done.

Running `xjc` creates 4 classes namely `ObjectFactory.java`,  `package-info.java`, class representing webservice request and class representing webservice response.

I overlooked to include `package-info.java` alongwith other 3 classes. This is the reason jaxb is unable to unmarshal the repsone.

If I dont include `ObjectFactory.java`, I get exception at server startup thrown by `org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller` bean defined in spring context file so I know I have to include it. But not including `package-info.java` fails silently causing frustration!

I have read in Stackoverflow and elsewhere that for unmarshal() method to accept just one argument- `javax.xml.transform.Source` and unmarshal I need to use `@XmlRootElement` annotation but that doesn't seem to be applicable to my case.